# Javax build uri link

Tags: java, rest, url, server-sent-events

in Java I am using the `javax` ´framework to connect to an server with `SSE`. For this purpose I need to build an url for accessing the server. The endpoint on the server has the formation `http://path/queryparam/path/pathparam/path`

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/events?topics=smarthome/items/chromecastchromecast6e63c8ef6787409f05664045a0bae715volumee9fe9f8fb4ff4c26872cba2980093a83/statechanged`
```

When I am trying to build it with `WebTarget` it is always destroying or reordering the parameters to: `http://path/pathParams/queryparams`

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/events/items/chromecastchromecast6e63c8ef6787409f05664045a0bae715volumee9fe9f8fb4ff4c26872cba2980093a83/statechanged?topics=smarthome
```

This is my code:

```
public WebTarget buildTarget(String path, String[] pathParams, Object[] pathParamObjects, String[] queryParams, Object[] queryParamObjects){

        WebTarget target = webRootTarget
                .path(path);



        for(int i = 0; i < pathParams.length; i++){
            target = target
                    .path("/{" + pathParams[i] + "}")
                    .resolveTemplate(pathParams[i], pathParamObjects[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < queryParams.length; i++){
            target = target
                    .queryParam(queryParams[i], queryParamObjects[i]);
        }
        logger.info(target.getUri().toString());
        return target;
    }

 WebTarget wt =requestHelper.buildTarget(
            "/events",
            new String[0],
            new Object[0],
            new String[]{"topics"},
            new String[]{"smarthome"});
    logger.info("wwt "+ wt.getUri());
    WebTarget wt2= wt.path("items/chromecastchromecast6e63c8ef6787409f05664045a0bae715volumee9fe9f8fb4ff4c26872cba2980093a83/statechanged");
```

I have tried many different ways to force the link to be build as described above. But no matter what the webtarget always changes the link so that the queryparameter is either standing at last position or the slashes ('/') are substituted by %2f which is the UTF-code I guess:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/events?topics=smarthome%2Fitems%2Fchromecastchromecast6e63c8ef6787409f05664045a0bae715volumee9fe9f8fb4ff4c26872cba2980093a83%2Fstatechanged%2F
```

So does anybody can tell me what the issue is and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is perfectly valid and normal to specify a slash in the query as `%2F`.  All servers will recognize that it is an encoded `/`.